# Moving Wordpress site: theme and plugins licenses paid by old website maintainer

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, web-hosting

I got a little job by a small society which already has a website made in Wordpress. Who made the website used a professional theme license and a few plugins (also with licenses). 
The website owner wants to move it to another provider keeping the existing url. 
I already made a backup of website and database, imported them in my local host and changed the pointing url in the "wp_options" table. I can see the website but the main slider (a paid plugin) and the admin menu icons are not rendered and I don't know why:

[image: screen]

If I inspect the slider, resources point to my local host so I really don't understand what happens.
Anyway, I can't even use the Theme Properties section and I think that both are unusable because of licenses.

My questions are..
Suppose we change provider (keeping the url) and move the website. It could work, even because the url is the same so everything should work as before. Now, can the previous maintainer revoke his licenses for theme and plugins in order to block it?

Or, anyway, should he grant licenses to my customer?

Or, even better, are these problems due to licenses or something else?

In any case, I'm gonna remake the website if something won't work properly, but a full save would be better to spare some time.

Thanks in advance and ask for more info if necessary!

**EDIT:** as asked in the comments, here is the screen where you can see that resources are taken from my local host: [image: Screen]
On the left, you can see that admin icons are "Dashicons" that are in the wordpress folder (already checked). 
On the right you can see that slider images point to localhost as I mentioned before.
I already recorded the load network resources and everything is loaded from my localhost but not rendered: [image: Screen network resources]

**EDIT 2:** SOLVED. I used the All-In-One WP Migration plugin as suggested by @Manjunath in the comments. It worked perfectly. Maybe I have done something wrong while manual importing the website. Thanks!

Comment: There are some good tutorials out there on how to change the URLs in the database itself. Pick one that you can understand best.

Comment: Can you show us the network tab of the resource inspector or it's console so we know that it's finding everything it should?

Comment: @GabrielFonseca I added stuff to the main post, thanks!

Comment: Is the new hosting PHP7 and the old not? There are several backward breaking changes in 7, some in 5.5 and 5.6,  Some of the more notable ones for WP `&&var[1]`  variable variable replacement with an array,  and the `/e` modifier in preg_replace, turn on wordpress debugging in the wp-config.php file, I've moved several sites with those 2 things breaking a few plugins,

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I'm testing it on my pc. My WAMP was using PHP 7.2, I tried 5.6 but nothing changed. Thanks for tip tho.

Comment: As I said some of those changes were in 5.5 and 5.6, you'd have to try the exact version it was hosted with originally.  Which I don't see mentioned.  There is also a plugin called Velvet blue, that will go and change domain in embedded images, which (unfortunately) most page builders do.  But if you don't see 404's in the network panel of the browser debuger (f12) I wouldn't bother with that.

Comment: if the wp site is not huge you can use wp all in one migration plugin, which exports and import everything like a clone including the wp creds too i.e., each and every files with config and database

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I checked it. The actual host php version is the same of my localhost. I'm gonna try the migration plugin mentioned by Manjunath

Comment: The plugin worked. Thanks @Manjunath!! Maybe I did something wrong in the manual migration. You saved my life. I'm gonna close the topic.

Comment: It's very easy to mess up manually moving a site, I've done it about 30 times, as I said recently I had to move 6 sites from 5.3 to 7.2, it was a big mess, but good luck, glad the plugin worked out for you!

Comment: @Thoughts Riff yaa we all have done same. After which i found out the plugin :)